# How was Amalgam planning to achieve their ultimate goal?

Tags: full-metal-panic

In the FMP light novels, the ultimate plan of the Big Bad Leonard Testarossa and the organization he heads, Amalgam, is to

> remake the *entire world* into one more to their liking, along similar lines to other anime villains such as Seele, Madara, etc. To that end they take over Merida Island and install a system built by Kaname.

How exactly were they planning on achieving this?

> How exactly Amalgam's technology was supposed to rewrite history and change the world is unclear to me. From what I can make out, it somehow involved time displacement that was related to the Whispereds' abilities (i.e. they were telepathically receiving information from the future).